# Django Rest Framework asking for authentication after sign in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-serializer

I am able to successfully login via Token Authentication. However, when getting another API, its asking for authentication.

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

views.py

```
class CreateQuiz(generics.ListCreateAPIView):    
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes =(IsAuthenticated,)
        
    def get_queryset(self):    
        return somequeryset
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK ={
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ),

}



from datetime import timedelta

REST_KNOX ={
    'USER_SERIALZIER' :'api.serializer.UserSerializer',
    'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=24*7),
}
```

when I test **http://127.0.0.0.1:8000/apis/v1/login/?username=xxxx.com&password=xxxx** on postman, I get succcessfully authenticated and returns

```
{
    "expiry": "2021-05-18T19:46:33.841420Z",
    "token": "f07a35897b070eabfcf1439c4495b8cede5fd9908135692e2c516127a926f2ab"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the token in the header of all future requests.

```
Authorization: Token <your token>
```

Also, you should use the POST instead of GET because the password will be visible in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. How can I add it to the request, could you please elaborate? Do I append it to my request url ? http://127.0.0.1:8000/apis/v1/quiz/$classId/$subject/$chaptervalue?format=json

Comment: Postman has a Headers tab. You can add it there when you make the request.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually calling it from flutter, so I probably have to figure out some other way.

Comment: Depends on your library. I use axios and I set it like this:  axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + token;